# C# AutoCAD | How to properly set the Icon on MenuItem in ContextMenuExtension

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm trying to set an Icon for a MenuItem in a ContextMenu Extension, but the icon is set with defects:
[image]

Original icon (16x16):
[image]

Code to set Icon:

```
polyline_item1.Icon = ACADConstructionPit.Properties.Resources.exchangeProfile;
```

How to properly set the Icon on MenuItem in ContextMenuExtension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Example]

Code for getting an image from a file using the template path (*%appdata%/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/POW_UPS.bundle/UI/_Images/*):

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get Icon for AutoCAD ContextMenuExtension: MenuItem.Icon 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inIconFileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static System.Drawing.Icon GetIconForAppFromPathFile(string inIconFileName, string inFolderPath = null)
    {
        System.Drawing.Icon _ImageSourceForApp = null;
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inIconFileName)) { return _ImageSourceForApp; }

            if (inFolderPath == null)
            {
                // path to image folder: %appdata%/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/POW_EPS.bundle/UI/_Images/
                var _PathToFolderIcons = $"{Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Autodesk", "ApplicationPlugins", "POW_EPS.bundle", "UI", "_Images")}";
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_PathToFolderIcons)) { return _ImageSourceForApp; }
                inFolderPath = _PathToFolderIcons;
            }

            IEnumerable<string> _AllPathIcons = Directory.GetFiles(inFolderPath, "*.png");
            string _PathIconFile = _AllPathIcons.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Contains(inIconFileName));
            Bitmap _BitmapFromFile = new Bitmap(_PathIconFile);
            Bitmap _ResizedBitmap = new Bitmap(_BitmapFromFile, new Size(16, 16));
            _ImageSourceForApp = Icon.FromHandle(_ResizedBitmap.GetHicon());

        }
        catch { }
        return _ImageSourceForApp;
    }
```

Example of icon installation:

```
menu_item.Icon = GetIconForAppFromPathFile("exchangeProfile.png");
```

---

But, unfortunately, not all icons can be installed correctly:
[image: Bad]

Original image (32x32):
[image: Original image (32x32)]